# How can you set the working directory quickly to a file's location in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, working-directory

The old method is the following :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new feature on RStudio.
Just right-click on the a script's tab and choose "Set Working Directory"

[image]

The script has to be saved first as an R file for this to work ([see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72697223/how-can-you-set-the-working-directory-quickly-to-a-files-location-in-rstudio/72697224#comment128410668_72697224))

Comment: This approach works when the script is already an R file. It does not work with unsaved tabs.